# How to make a django field like a RadioSelector inside a django form wizard

Tags: django, django-formwizard

I need to define one field of my django model in a way that takes either X/Z, True/False or 0/1. I mean when I select one checkbox I expect be able to choose just one checkbox not both together(Like select between Yes or No) and after submit I see one of those mentioned values in the database table field.

What I have tried so far:

```
from model_utils import Choices
class Post(models.Model):
     STATUS = Choices(
       ('x', ('select X')),
       ('z', ('Select Z'))
     )

    action_style = models.CharField(
        max_length=32,
        choices=STATUS,
        default='x'
        )
```

and in form:

```
class Postform(forms.ModelForm):

    STATUS = Choices(
           ('x', 'select X'),
           ('z', 'Select Z')
         )

    status = forms.MultipleChoiceField(
        widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple,
        required=False, choices=STATUS
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ['status']
```

and in template:

```
<form method="POST" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{ wizard.management_form }}
            {{ wizard.form.action_style }}
             <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>
```

Comment: sounds like a radio button. correct ?

Comment: Yes something like that,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might cause problem for choosing only one.

```
forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple
```

According to django Doc about [CheckboxSelectMultiple](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/forms/widgets/#checkboxselectmultiple) and related [SelectMultiple](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/forms/widgets/#django.forms.SelectMultiple), it allows **multiple selection: `<select multiple>...</select>`**

You might need CheckBoxInput[3](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/forms/widgets/#checkboxinput) or use RadioSelect [4](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/forms/widgets/#radioselect).

in forms.py, replace

```
status = forms.MultipleChoiceField(
        widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple,
        required=False, choices=STATUS
    )
```

with

```
status = forms.MultipleChoiceField(
        widget = forms.RadioSelect(choices=STATUS)
    )
```